# Python argparse: Too few arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use the argparse library in Python.  I want to have the user do something like:

```
python my_script.py csv_name.csv [--dryrun]
```

where `--dryrun` is an optional parameter.

I then have the user enter an API key and secret key.  When I run my code, I get past entering the API and secret keys and then I get:

```
usage: my_script.py [-h] csv dryrun
salesforceImporter.py: error: too few arguments
```

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    api_key = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter API Key: ')
    secret_key = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter Secret Key: ')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("csv")
    parser.add_argument("dryrun")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    validate_csv_name(args.csv)

    is_dry_run = args.dryrun == '--dryrun'
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an optional `--dry-run` argument, you may use the following snippet:

```
parser.add_argument('--dry-run', action='store_true')
```

Calling your script using `python my_script.py csv_name.csv --dry-run` will result to `args.dry_run` being `True`. Not putting the option will result to it being `False`

Answer (score 6):

When you use the following syntax:

```
parser.add_argument("csv")
parser.add_argument("dryrun")
```

You're adding these as positional -- *required* -- arguments. Only arguments with a leading dash or two are optional.

See [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags):

> The add_argument() method must know whether an optional argument, like -f or --foo, or a positional argument, like a list of filenames, is expected. The first arguments passed to add_argument() must therefore be either a series of flags, or a simple argument name. For example, an optional argument could be created like:

```
>>> parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
```

Comment: So now I'm doing something like: parser.add_argument("--dryrun").  Unfortunately, now I get:                  usage: my_script.py [-h] [--dryrun DRYRUN] csv
my_script.py: error: argument --dryrun: expected one argument